# int main(int argc,char* argv[]) why does argc gives 2 argument?

Tags: c++, c

If I understood correctly using of `int main(int argc,char* argv[])` , whenever I've declared 4 integer argc must be 5. For example;

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
int portNb = 0;
int leftMotorHandle;
int rightMotorHandle;
int sensorHandle;


if (argc>=5)
{
    portNb=atoi(argv[1]);
    leftMotorHandle=atoi(argv[2]);
    rightMotorHandle=atoi(argv[3]);
    sensorHandle=atoi(argv[4]);
}
else
{
    printf("Indicate following arguments: 'portNumber leftMotorHandle  rightMotorHandle sensorHandle'!\n");
    extApi_sleepMs(55000);
    return 0;
}
```

But argc's value is 2 when i debugged the code. How can i be sure that argc has value of 5 ?

Comment: What do you pass on the command line when you run your program?

Comment: `argv` and `argc` are there to let you access arguments passed to your program. More arguments, more `argv` values and bigger `argc` to indicate so. Are you passing 4 arguments to your program?

Comment: If you want argc to be equal to five, then you should provide four command line arguments.

Comment: A sample input command line along with the resulting `argc` may allow us to shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Looks like C. C and C++ are **different** languages, pick **one**. And the answer is simple: by passing four arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> If I understood correctly using of 'int main(int argc,char* argv[])' , whenever I've declared 4 integer argc must be 5.

`argc` and `argv` have nothing to do with the number of variables you declare within your program. `argc` means the number of arguments you provide when you **run** it from the command line. `argv` is the array of char pointers that point to your arguments (including the name of your program itself).

Assume your program called `proc`. You would need to run it from command line as (or else you would need to find out from your IDE how to provide the command line arguments).

```
./proc 5 10 15 20
```

The numbers 5, 10, 15, 20 would be your `argv[1]` .. `argv[4]`

Answer (score 0):

You should input not less than 4 arguments from the command line.

Separate the arguments by `space`.

Answer (score 0):

**Int argc**  is argument count, means how many arguments your are passing, including program name.

**char pointer array** represent arguments